# PHP creating url with parameters

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP and want to create a link with parameters.

So I used this :

```
<li>
  <!-- $GLOBALS["ROOT_PATH"] is where my index.php file located -->
  <a href="<?php echo $GLOBALS["ROOT_PATH"]."/Views/pages/profile.php"; ?>">
     Profile
  </a>
</li>
```

but when I click on the page it doesn't send me to the page or do anything. When I look at the URL it's something like `file:///C:/bla/bla/bla/Views/pages/profile.php`

Edit:
Basically, I want to use this in my header.php but my files are :

> index.php

> Views/pages/profile.php

and so on.

When I use the relative path for the header the path changes for these pages. How can I solve this?

Comment: This is, because it is the absolute file path. For the http docs root, just omit the path.

Comment: To clarify, `<a href="/Views/pages/profile.php">Profile</a>` should be all you need. You don't need to output the absolute URL like `<a href="https://www.website.com/Views/pages/profile.php">Profile</a>`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see `file://` in the URL unless you opened the page directly in the browser (file...open...) instead of running it off a server

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones As I explained in the newly edited post, It works fine in index.php, but when it comes to the other pages it looks like `Views/pages/profile.php/Views/pages/profile.php` in the URL.

Comment: Are you sure the `href` value is `/Views/pages/profile.php` instead of `Views/pages/profile.php` (note the leading slash). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#examples for examples of different types of links.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it using some tricky way but it works :

```
function createLink($url,$text,$class){
      echo "<li>";
      // Gets the current php file name.
      $basename = substr(strtolower(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),0,strlen(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))-4);
      if($basename !== "index"){
        $url = "../../".$url;
      }
      echo '<a href="'. $url . '">';
      echo '<span class="'.$class.'"></span>';
      echo ' '.$text.'';
      echo "</a>";
      echo "</li>";
    }
```

So it just add the relative path if the file name is not index.php.